# Create additional columns when using "Create Table As"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a table using the `CREATE TABLE AS` Statement. Script looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE table2
AS
  SELECT column1, column2, ..., columnN
  FROM table1
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 50;
```

My question is, can I create additional columns on table2 that don't exist in table1 inside the `CREATE TABLE AS` Statement or do I have to resort to `ALTER` afterwards?

EDIT: For example table1 contains ID, FULLNAME, STATUS and I wanna add a column somewhere in between called AGE

I am using Oracle Sql

Comment: I think you need to do an alter.

Comment: I dont know oracle anymore so I wont post an official answer.  I think that you can add columns in your select list.   Something like Select column1, column2, convert(int,1) column3, convert(varchar(100), "") column4 from table1...

Comment: Yes you can. What columns?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz For example table1 contains ID, FULLNAME, STATUS and I wanna add a column somewhere in between called AGE. EDIT: Adding this to the question

Comment: With some data or with NULLs?

Comment: @If I can do it with data at the same statement yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add whatever you'd like to the `SELECT`

```
CREATE TABLE table2
AS
  SELECT column1, column2, ..., columnN, 
         trunc(months_between(birth_date,sysdate)/12) age,
         'Some string' another_column
  FROM table1
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 50;
```